# Is the hadith of Aisha RA that she used to veil her face while in ihram sahih?

Tags: women, hijab, hajj

As salamu alaykum wa rahmatullahi wa baraktuhu,

‘Aishah narrated (may Allah be pleased with her) said: “The riders used to pass by us when we were with the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) in ihram, and when they drew near to us we would lower our jilbabs from our heads over our faces, then when they had passed we would uncover them again. (Narrated by Abu Dawud, 1833; Ibn Majah, 2935; classed as sahih by Ibn Khuzaymah (4,203) and by al-Albani in Kitab Jilbab al-Marah al-Muslimah) But this was marked as daif by Shaykh Albani (The following hadith is listed as "Da’if (Darussalam)" (weak) at sunnah.com but others have graded it as sahih)
Could you clarify?

I'm not sure what to make of these two conflicting classifications.

Question: Is this hadith sahih?

Comment: Related: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/64563/